# How to troubleshoot web errors on the Apple developer forum?

Tags: safari, websites

I have an AppleID and paid $99 dollars to enroll in the iOS Developer program. I tried creating new thread in iOS Developer Forum but end up in blank white screen. I couldn't see anything on the screen.

Has anyone a suggestion on what the requirements (or how to troubleshoot) the developer forum web page when you run into issues?

Comment: Did you quit the browser and try again? Any browser extensions installed?

Comment: Did you try a different browser?

Comment: no haven't. I will try it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually things like that are caused by browser extensions or an odd interaction between a specific browser version and the code on the site.

Have you looked over the basic support page for the Developer Forums?

https://developer.apple.com/support/resources/developer-forums.html

It has a "contact us" form if you can't solve this by ensuring an up to date (and unmodified) version of Safari isn't rendering the web site properly for you.